# JavaScript + Querystring + div

Tags: javascript

How to load content in to a html page. please note IM not allowed to use php or C. Only javascript and html.

for example

load Page B in to Page A

http:myweb.com/index.html?load=pageb

thank you.

Comment: are you asking how to get the URL (query part) from JavaScript?

Comment: yes 
using url links and load content in to div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plain JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getUrlVars() {
var map = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    map[key] = value;
});
return map;
}    
function createRequestObject() {
            var ro;
            // Mozilla, Safari,...
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if (ro.overrideMimeType) {
                    ro.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
                    // See note below about this line
                }
                // IE
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    ro = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {}
                }
            }
            if (!ro) {
                alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
                return false;
            }
            return ro;
        }
        function sndReq(param,server,handler) {
            //location.href = server+"?"+action; //uncomment if you need for debugging
            http = createRequestObject();
            http.open('GET', server, true);
            http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            http.onreadystatechange = handler;
            http.send(param);
        }
        handler_function = function()
        {
            if(http.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (http.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("your_div_element").innerHTML = http.responseText;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                }
            }
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="your_div_element"></div>
<script>
var getvars= getUrlVars();
sndReq(null, getvars['action'], handler_function);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to request content via url link

Comment: Use the sndReq(null,"b.html", handler_function); where b.html is the url like http://yourserver.com/b.html. Remember you can't request content from an other domain like http://theirserver.com/b.html.

Comment: could you please just the url link which load the  into 

<div id="your_div_element"></div>

Comment: Sorry, I do not get the question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.
I just want to know how load the content from (1.html) into default page (main page on server), using the above code.

somthing like

www.myweb.com/index.html?action=file1.html

Comment: You need to request the http GET variable (action=file1.html). Take a look here: http://snipplr.com/view/19838/get-url-parameters/ on how to do that in JavaScript

Comment: How ?
how do i get variable in Martin Hoegh code. and load content in to div location.

Comment: I've now updated my answer and put in the getUrlVar() function. So now you can call martins_script.html?action=file1.html. I've not tested the script and it may be buggy.

Comment: Sorry Im an total nowbie, i do this just for hobby with a notepad. i was hoping to find a working sample.  

thank you anyway.

Comment: Its ok. I've now tested the script and updated. Is works now. Put the script in a file, call it something like "test.html". Write a new html file, called it eg "get.html" and write some text in it. Put both files in your web root. Call test.html?action=get.html and bingo!

Comment: Just corrected one more thing and made a live example: http://wms.mapuse.net/stackoverflow/test.html?action=get.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Issue an **AJAX** request to Page B
2. Get the contents using **responseText**
3. Display the contents inside a div using **innerHTML** property.

If you can use a js framework then I would suggest jQuery and @marcgg's answer will do it.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
//Page A
<html>
<head><title>Page A</title></head>
<body>
<div id="pageB"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pageB').load('pageb.html')
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://some.com/page.html",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "here's your data: " + msg );
     jQuery("#yourDivID").html(msg);
   }
 });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax

edit: added how to put it into a div